# Twitch API Embed in Discord.Net C# Loop/Timer not Spamming Channel

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

i have a currently working embed post when a channel given in the config is live on twitch.
I want to make a loop that the function gets checked every 5 Minutes if the channel is live or not (live-alert for dc).
I use a classic timer and its looping and spamming the channel cuz i dont know which function i could use for it. MessageCaching is in the DiscordSocketClient config active.

I want: that its not spamming the embed. A little check needed to check if the streamer is live and embed already posted.. when not live check if the streamer was 5 minutes not live then check till hes live again (when streamers internet is reconnecting the stream embed dont need to get spammed)

Here is the full code of my twitch"handler"

````
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CentricXBot.Services
{
    public class TwitchHandler
    {
       
    // setup fields to be set later in the constructor
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
        private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _logger;
        public TwitchHandler(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            //Timer Infinite Loop need to check if not Live still Loop if live and posted dont post any new but still checks
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000); //10 seconds
            timer.Elapsed += async ( sender, e ) => TwitchTest();
            timer.Start();

            // juice up the fields with these services
            // since we passed the services in, we can use GetRequiredService to pass them into the fields set earlier
            _config = services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            _client = services.GetRequiredService<DiscordSocketClient>();
            _logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CommandHandler>>();
            _services = services;

            // hook into these events with the methods provided below
             _client.Ready += TwitchTest;
        }
    public class Datum
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")] public string ID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("userId")] public string user_id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("user_name")] public string user_name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("game_id")] public string game_id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("game_name")] public string game_name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("type")] public string type { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("title")] public string title { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("viewer_count")] public int viewer_count { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("thumbnail_url")] public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
    }
    public class StreamObject
    {
        public List<Datum> data { get; set; }

    }   
    public class ProfileTwitch
    {
        [JsonProperty("profile_image_url")] public string profile_image_url { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProfileObject
    {
        public List<ProfileTwitch> data { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task TwitchTest()
    {
        //Create new HttpClient
        var client = new HttpClient();
        //Send client-id and oauth token to Twitch API
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Client-ID", $"{_config["clientid"]}"); 
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", $"{_config["oauth"]}");
       //Get Stream Info
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login={_config["live-alert-streamer"]}");
        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;
        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var stream = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StreamObject>(jsonString);

        //Get Profile Info just for the profile picture
        HttpResponseMessage responseUser = await client.GetAsync($"https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login={_config["live-alert-streamer"]}");
        HttpContent responseUserContent = responseUser.Content;
        string jsonProfileString = await responseUser.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProfileObject>(jsonProfileString);

    //Check if the channel is not offline
    if (!(stream == default(StreamObject) || stream.data.Count == 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Live: {stream.data[0].type}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Streamer: {stream.data[0].user_name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Title: {stream.data[0].title}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Game: {stream.data[0].game_name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"ThumbnailURL: {stream.data[0].thumbnail_url.Replace("{width}x{height}","1920x1080")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Viewer Count: {stream.data[0].viewer_count}");
        
        //Create Embed
        var embed = new EmbedBuilder{};
        embed.WithFooter(footer => footer.Text = "CentricX")
            .WithTitle($"{stream.data[0].title}")
            .WithAuthor($"{stream.data[0].user_name} is now live on Twitch!", $"{profile.data[0].profile_image_url}")
            
            .WithImageUrl($"{stream.data[0].thumbnail_url.Replace("{width}x{height}","1920x1080")}")
            .WithDescription($"Playing {stream.data[0].game_name} for {stream.data[0].viewer_count} viewers \n [Watch Stream](https://twitch.tv/{stream.data[0].user_name})")
            .WithColor(Color.Blue)
            .WithUrl($"https://twitch.tv/{stream.data[0].user_name}")
            .WithCurrentTimestamp();

        //Send Embed to channel
        ulong ChannelID = Convert.ToUInt64(_config["live-alert-channel"]);
        var sendchannel = _client.GetChannel(ChannelID) as IMessageChannel; 
        var msg = await sendchannel.SendMessageAsync(embed: embed.Build()); 
       


    }
        //If channel is offline do
        else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not Live");
    };
            _logger.LogInformation("Twitch Handler loaded");  
    }
    }
}```
````

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. `I use a classic timer and its looping and spamming the channel cuz i dont know which function i could use for it` -- you don't know what function to use for what?

Comment: Ok my question:
what i can do that my twitch embed its not spammed every 10 seconds. What i need to change. I have my timer what loops the TwitchTest Task and i want that it checks: if embed already posted and the channel is not "not" live for more than 5 minutesand goes live again post embed again.. like a normal live-alert

Comment: You can implement a Boolean that represents the state of the notification. The first thing you do after checking if online is check if notification sent. If no, send the embed and set the bool to true. If yes, do nothing (return). Similarly in the offline section, you check if the bool is still true, if it is, set it to false so that the next time it goes online you'll send the notification again.

Comment: Ok thats all? thank you alot, didnt think about boolean vars...

Comment: yeah and the timer is now on 5 minutes instead of 10 seconds to dont have trouble with the twitch api called to often. thank you alot. :) next time i need to ask about reaction roles cuz my function is not working will create a stack when my code is better formatted :)